# Create Restful Service Using Repository

Tags: c#, web-services, interface

I have a mvc application. I am using repository pattern and dependecy injection patterns. Here is a simple interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ICategoryService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Category> GetAll();

        Category Add(Category category);
    }
```

And a concrete class that implements this interface:

```
public class CategoryManager : ICategoryService
{
    private readonly ICategoryDal _categoryDal;

    public CategoryManager(ICategoryDal categoryDal)
    {
        _categoryDal = categoryDal;
    }

    public List<Category> GetAll()
    {
        return _categoryDal.GetWithSp();
    }

    public List<Category> GetAll(int a)
    {
        return _categoryDal.GetList();
    }

    public Category Add(Category category)
    {

       return _categoryDal.Add(category);
    }
}
```

I inject this concrete class to interface in global.asax.
Now I need to create a web service to expose some methods in this interface (this interface just an example. Not only this one). 
How can I do that with a few effort? Because most of this methods already works on web application, maybe just a few methods needs to be added.

Can I use this interaface as a contract, instead of creating a new one? Or what should I do when I also need to use another interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it!
Enterprise level application architecture with web API's using Entity Framework, Generic Repository Pattern and Unit of Work.

[using Web Api with generic repository](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990492/RESTful-Day-sharp-Enterprise-Level-Application)